# How do you round a Double down to the nearest integer in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, double, rounding

How do you round a Double down to the nearest integer in VB .NET?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is pretty old, but the accepted answer of using `Math.Truncate` is technically incorrect: Truncate rounds *towards zero*, not down. For example, -1.5 is rounded to -1 instead of -2.

In order to always round *down*, use `Math.Floor`.

Answer (score 8):

Are we talking VB.NET or VB6? In VB.NET use [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic we have used:

```
dim d as decimal = 1.50

dim I as int64 = convert.toint64(D)
```